# Expected to find ")"

Tags: flutter

I can't seem to solve the problem in line 57
problem: error: Expected to find ')'.

I tried to find if there is non-paired paranthesis or so,but no luck i guess.
I tried paranthesis validators but it got worse.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(

            child: _isLoggedIn

                ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(_googleSignIn.currentUser.photoUrl, height: 50.0, width: 50.0,),
                Text(_googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName),
                OutlineButton( child: Text("Logout"), onPressed: ()
                {_logout();})
                ];//line 57
                ]:
              child: Center(
                child: _myWidget(context),
              ),
            )

                : Center(
              child: OutlineButton(

                child: Text("Login with Google"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _login();
                },
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: nope.It caused more errors.

Comment: How about the closing square bracket? I see two closing and one opening `]`

Comment: solved.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to give the Column both children and child.
The column only takes the children as a parameter.

Try to remove

`child: Center(
        child: _myWidget(context),
    ),`

from line 59, the `;` from line 57 and the `]:` from line 58