# No matter what I do, this error Expected to find ')' won't go away

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep getting this error

> Expected to find ')'

and it seems to be the reason why I can't run my project. I have checked these issues:

- [getting expected ')' '}' in expression list. how do i solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059645/getting-expected-in-expression-list-how-do-i-solve-this)
- [Expected to find ")"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254260/expected-to-find)

but they don't seem to give any solution that could help me. I have gone through the code countless times but can't find any unpaired brackets or curly braces. I don't even know if that's the issue or there's something else. Problem is in line 177

```
import 'package:fuodz/translations/order_details.i18n.dart';

  class FirebaseService {
    static NotificationModel notificationModel;
    static FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    static dynamic notificationPayloadData;

    //
    static NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics;
    static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

    static setUpFirebaseMessaging() async {
      //Request for notification permission
      /*NotificationSettings settings = */
      await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

      // settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized
      //
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      //handling the notification process
      // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
      // If you have skipped STEP 3 then change app_icon to @mipmap/ic_launcher
      var initializationSettingsAndroid =
          new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/notification_icon');
      var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
      var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      );

      //
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification,
      );

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );

      //
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "${AppStrings.notificationChannel}",
        "${AppStrings.appName}",
        "${AppStrings.appName}",
        importance: Importance.high,
        priority: Priority.high,
      );

      var iosPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

      platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iosPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      );

      //subscribing to all topic
      firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("all");

      //on notification received in background
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessageHandler);
      //on notification tap tp bring app back to life
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
        print("Message Opened App Data ${message.data}");
        saveNewNotification(message);
        selectNotification("From onMessageOpenedApp");
      });

      //normal notification listener
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        print("Notification Data ${message.data}");
        saveNewNotification(message);
        showNotification(message);
      });
    }

    //Handle background message
    static Future<void> onBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
      print("Background Data ${message.data}");
      saveNewNotification(message);
      selectNotification("From onBackgroundMessage");
    }

    //write to notification list
    static saveNewNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
      //
      notificationPayloadData = message.data;
      //Saving the notification
      notificationModel = NotificationModel();
      notificationModel.title = message.notification.title;
      notificationModel.body = message.notification.body;
      notificationModel.timeStamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

      //add to database/shared pref
      NotificationService.addNotification(notificationModel);
    }

    //
    static showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
      try {
        //

        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification.title,
          message.notification.body,
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: "From show",
        );
      } catch (error) {
        print("Notification Show error ===> ${error.message}");
        print("Notification Show error ===> ${error.details}");
        print("Notification Show error ===> ${error.stacktrace}");
      }
    }

    //handle on notification selected
    static Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
      print("Payload ==> $payload");
      try {
        //
        final isChat = notificationPayloadData != null &&
            notificationPayloadData["is_chat"] != null;
        final isOrder = notificationPayloadData != null &&
            notificationPayloadData["is_order"] != null;
        //
        if (isChat) {
          //
          dynamic user = jsonDecode(notificationPayloadData['user']);
          dynamic peer = jsonDecode(notificationPayloadData['peer']);
          String chatPath = notificationPayloadData['path'];
          //
          Map<String, PeerUser> peers = {
            '${user['id']}': PeerUser(
              id: '${user['id']}',
              name: "${user['name']}",
              image: "${user['photo']}",
            ),
            '${peer['id']}': PeerUser(
              id: '${peer['id']}',
              name: "${peer['name']}",
              image: "${peer['photo']}",
            ),
          };
          //
          final peerRole = peer["role"];
          //
          final chatEntity = ChatEntity(
            mainUser: peers['${user['id']}'],
            peers: peers,
            //don't translate this
            path: chatPath,
            title: peer["role"] == null
                ? "Chat with".i18n + " ${peer['name']}"
              : peerRole == 'driver'
                      : "Chat with driver".i18n, //line 177
                      : "Chat with vendor".i18n,
          );
          AppService.navigatorKey.currentContext.navigator.pushNamed(
            AppRoutes.chatRoute,
            arguments: chatEntity,
          );
        }
        //order
        else if (isOrder) {
          //
          final order = Order(
            id: int.parse(notificationPayloadData['order_id'].toString()),
          );
          //
          AppService.navigatorKey.currentContext.navigator.pushNamed(
            AppRoutes.orderDetailsRoute,
            arguments: order,
          );
        }
        //regular notifications
        else {
          AppService.navigatorKey.currentContext.navigator.pushNamed(
              AppRoutes.notificationDetailsRoute,
              arguments: notificationModel);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print("Error opening Notification ==> $error");
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the output i get when i run it

```
    [Launching lib\main.dart on HUAWEI GRA UL00 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/services/firebase.service.dart:177:23: Error: Expected ')' before this.
                      : "Chat with driver".i18n,
                      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
* [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
* [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
* [√] Chrome - develop for the web
* [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
* [√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
* [√] Connected device (1 available)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an issure with ternary operator

```dart
  title: peer["role"] == null
              ? "Chat with".i18n + " ${peer['name']}"
              : peerRole == 'driver'
                ? "Chat with driver".i18n //line 177
                : "Chat with vendor".i18n,
```